# Loss of service in GAE's deployment method using Traffic Migrate?

Tags: deployment, google-app-engine, traffic-management

I want to know if there is any possible downtime in GAE's method of "silent" deployments. I'm using

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

and deploying apps with `-no-promote --no-stop-previous-version` flags before going to App Engine and migrating traffic from old to new version.

Is there still a possibility of a client noticing there is a deployment going on?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is still room for a deployment to impact customer experience - you should migrate traffic to the new version gradually, not all at once.

From [this section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability#switching_default_version) in [Designing for Scale](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability):

> **Use traffic splitting when switching to a new default version**
>
> A high traffic application may get errors or higher latency when
>   updating to a new version in the following scenarios:
>
> - Complete update of a new default version
> - Set the default version
>
> Once the update is complete, App Engine will send requests to the new
>   version. However, the new version may take some time to spin up enough
>   instances to handle all traffic. During this period, requests can
>   potentially sit on the pending queue and may time out.
>
> Therefore, in order to minimize latency and errors, we recommend that
>   customers use [traffic splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/splitting-traffic) to move traffic gradually to a
>   new version before making it the default.
>
> An application may serve requests from both versions while you are
>   moving traffic to the new version. In most cases, this will not cause
>   any problems. However, if you have an incompatibility in the cached
>   objects used by an application then you will need to ensure that users
>   go to the same version of an application during their session. You
>   will need to code this into your application logic.